# Aspose epub tables set border width

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

My greetings!

I'm working with the Aspose lib and converting files to the epub. The problem is that the default border width of the table (in the doc that was converted by Aspose) is 0.5pt. It looks all fine on nook or PC, but iPad or HTML browser doesn't render those borders because of their small value. It shows them only if I zoom in for like 300%. I've been trying to find how to set the table border width in Aspose, but no luck. I've found something like: `table.SetBorders(LineStyle, lineWidth(double), Color);`, but it changes the whole bunch of parameters.

Do you have any ideas of how to set the border width of the table for the doc to be converted to the epub?

EDIT:

Ok, I've tried to manually reset the border width, but (surprise!) all of the border variable values are the same in the debug mode, so there is no way I could choose only the standard borders to be modified. Here is the code:

```
    /**
     * Performs single table border linewidth increasing due to the bugged iPad epub rendering. 
     */
    private void reformatSingleBorderWidth(Border border)
    {
        if (border != null && border.LineWidth < 1.0 && border.LineStyle == LineStyle.None)
        {
            border.LineWidth = 1.0;
        }
    }


  foreach (Table table in doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Table, true)) {
      foreach (Row row in table.Rows) {
           foreach (Cell cell in row.Cells) {
                BorderCollection borders = cell.CellFormat.Borders;

                reformatSingleBorderWidth(borders.Left);
                reformatSingleBorderWidth(borders.Right);
                reformatSingleBorderWidth(borders.Top);
                reformatSingleBorderWidth(borders.Bottom);
            }
       }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like a rendering issue. I opened Aspose saved epub files on different readers, most work fine. The borders were absent in iBooks too. Could you try NeoSoar for iPad, it seems to render correctly.

Comment: Hi, Saqib! Again you are helping me.. :) The problem appears only in the default iPad epub viewer, other devices work fine, like the nook one. I will try to use NeoSoar and let you know.. I found this article on forum - http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/487553/word-to-html-table-border-width-issues.aspx - but it didn't help.

Comment: I mean the problem is that most of the people use iBook, but not the NeoSoar.. :(

Comment: I already realized that most people use iBooks. Your best bet would be to get support in Aspose forums. May be there is a bug that needs fixing.

Comment: Well, it looks like there is. Right now I'm implementing the way I've shown in my edit. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: You can change the width with cell.CellFormat.Borders.LineWidth property.